# Kony loading screen customization

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am using loading screen in kony by following api-

```
kony.application.showLoadingScreen("BusyIndicator","Loading data...",constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_FULL_SCREEN, true,true,null);
```

BusyIndicator is custom skin made by me which includes background color black with 35% transparency.

However I am getting text 'Loading data...' in black color.

Please help me to customize this text by changing text color and size.

Comment: remove double quotes("") from your custom skin BUSYINDICATOR.
I hope it will work.As I am using like this.
kony.application.showLoadingScreen(LoadingSkn, "Loading data..", constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_ONLY_CENTER, true, true, null);

Comment: Please mention the platform you are targeting ,though kony has wrapped API's ,the real behavior differs platform by platform

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply an existing skin (e.g "slTextWhite") available in your project and use the same in code like below:

```
kony.application.showLoadingScreen("slTextWhite","Please wait",constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_ONLY_CENTER,true,true,{});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
kony.application.showLoadingScreen("sknLoading"," loading ....", constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_FULL_SCREEN, true, true,     {shouldShowLabelInBottom: "true", separatorHeight:200})
```

where **sknLoading** to be defined in common skin -- you will see at the bottom "*common*" in skin.

you can set background color, font color and other properties too.